# How to log a JSON without escape characters with the log module in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

When I use the log module to log something, the log message prints escape characters instead of interpreting it. For instance, consider the following code.

```
import ballerina/log;

public function main() {
    json jsonObject = {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "New York"
    };
    log:printInfo("Hello this is your json object: " + jsonObject.toJsonString());
}
```

When I run the above code, it logs the following.

```
time = 2023-11-09T15:15:10.935+05:30 level = INFO module = org/test message = "Hello this is your json object: {\"name\":\"John Doe\", \"age\":30, \"city\":\"New York\"}"
```

How can I make the program log the line without escape characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the JSON object is passed to the `message` parameter, it is converted to a JSON string, as the `message` parameter expects to print a string as expected by the user. Since the use case is to print the JSON as it is (i.e., print the JSON as key-value pairs), the JSON parameter should be provided as a `payload` parameter, as shown below.

```
import ballerina/log;

public function main() {
    json jsonObject = {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "New York"
    };
    log:printInfo("Hello this is your json object", payload = jsonObject);
}
```

The above code generates the following output:

```
time=2024-01-08T11:53:30.462+05:30 level=INFO module="" message="Hello this is your json object" payload={"name":"John Doe","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

Comment: Looks like `message` and  `payload` are undocumented magic parameters. The official [log](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/log/2.9.0#printInfo) module documentation only says: `function printInfo(string msg, error? 'error, StackFrame[]? stackTrace, *KeyValues keyValues)` and documentation for `KeyValues` don't mention these parameters either.

Comment: Ok, I got this. The used parameter names in the answer are 1) plain wrong: it's not `message` but `msg` and 2) `payload` is not a special name but can be anything you like (e.g. `foobar = jsonObject`) because `*KeyValues keyValues` parameter uses [included record parameter](https://ballerina.io/learn/advanced-general-purpose-language-features/#included-record-parameters) Ballerina feature.